# Hex color values in Android layouts are not being displayed accurately

Tags: android, android-layout, colors

I have a background image that has a consistent color all along the right side. I want the background color of the Activity to match so that the image can display full height with the correct aspect ratio for the width (anchored from the left). I don't want the color switch that is currently showing:

[image: Imgur]

I used a color dropper tool to get the hex value of the purple used in the image (the left side of the screenshot). It's hex value is `#4A2D70`. I then created a `color` resource:

```
<color name="purpleBackground">#4A2D70</color>
```

and set it as the background color of the RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purpleBackground">
```

The graphical layout preview matches the screenshot above, and when I run this in the emulator or on the device, the purple used for the RelativeLayout that shows is not the same hex value as the one I specify. I used the color dropper tool again to compare from the emulator, and this is what I get: `#391C5D`

I've also tried playing around with alpha settings and setting the RelativeLayout background to white and using this `purpleBackground` as the background color of the ImageView.

To reiterate my main question: **Why don't the hex color values translate directly? Is there a solution or workaround?**

**Edit:** This is the theme I'm using:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomTheme.ActionBar</item>
  <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/CustomTheme.EditText</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What theme are you using? Maybe you use one with transparent background?

Comment: Yes. I would venture a guess that this is due to transparency somewhere.

Comment: Okay, something adding transparency or shading would make sense. I have a custom theme that extends Theme.Holo.Light. I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did figure out why this didn't work, but I did use a simple and effective workaround with a background image. I simply copied a very thin slice of the right side of the background image for the Activity. Then I set it as the `android:background` attribute of the RelativeLayout that holds the ImageView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background_slice" >
```

Side note: the ImageView is set as follows to match height and maintain its aspect ratio. It's anchored to the left side so I end up with the space to fill on the right side, which is where the background_slice shows through.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_background" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with white #FFFFFF and you should be able to see if the color is being interpreted wrong, or if the picker is giving you the wrong value.

Comment: Good troubleshooting idea. White is correct but red (#FF0000) comes through as #F80016. So maybe it's a transparency or shading being applied somewhere?

Comment: Might have something to do with view pixel format? RGB565 (historical) vs RGB888...